# How to use unsplash to generate different random images within a loop

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I created a todo list project which contains an image for each one. I'm using unsplash to generate random images but I'm getting the same image for all of them. How do I get a different image for each task that I create

I'm using the MEAN stack to create a todo list project. I used *ngFor to loop through all the task to display an image for each one on my website but all of them have the same image.

home.component.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.componentGetAllTasks();
      this.randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
  }

  componentGetAllTasks(){
    let obs = this._httpService.serviceGetAllTasks();
    obs.subscribe(data =>{
      console.log('Got all tasks from component', data);
      this.tasks = data['tasks'];
      this.randomNumber()
    })
  }
```

http.service.ts

```
  serviceGetAllTasks(){
    return this._http.get('/tasks');
  }
```

Controller

```
    all: (req, res)=>{
        Task.find({}, (err, tasks)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({error: 'Cannot find all tasks', err});
            } else {
                res.json({message: 'Found all tasks!!!', tasks})
            }
        })
    },
```

HTML

```
<div class="container card-container task-container">
    <div class="card mb-4"  *ngFor='let task of tasks'>
        <div class="row no-gutters" >
            <div class="col-md-4 gallery">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig={{randomNumber}}" class="card-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 ">
                <div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title"><input (click)="componentDelete(task._id)" id="delete-me" class="checkbox mr-2" type="checkbox">Title: {{task.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Description: {{task.description}}</p>
                    <p class='card-title'>Due Date: <small class='bold'> {{task.dueDate | date:"fullDate"}}</small></p>
                    <button (click)="componentGetTask(task._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-left mr-3">Edit</button>
                    <button class='btn btn-danger'>Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outcome I'm trying to succeed is, by using the unsplash website, for each task that is displayed has a different image. Your help is very much appreciated :->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pham,

You are generating your random number only once at your component initialization.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.componentGetAllTasks();
  this.randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
```

The expression `(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))` returns a integer between 0 and 9 and it's stored in `this.randomNumber`. Bytheway, you cannot run `this.randomNumber` as a function like you did in the method `componentGetAllTasks()` because it's not a function.

So you always get the same image because you only generated the randomNumber once. To fix this, you would need to generate this number for every entry of your tasks. You could have a method that returns a random number

```
getRandomNumber() {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
```

and add this method to your template

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig={{getRandomNumber()}}" class="card-img">
```

Remember that this returns a random number, meaning that you can get the same number multiple times.

Comment: WooooooHoooooooo!!!!!!! Thanks this did it! Also thx for the extra explanation and tips . Appreciate it Douglas! But I did get an error: 

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'src: https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=5'. Current value: 'src: https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=9

Could you explain what the error is and help figure out this bug?

Comment: Thx for your help! But is there a way to get rid of the error I get?

Comment: That's a trick error to get rid without taking a  deeper look at the code but you can take a look at this article [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) to understand what it is and how to solve it. If you recreate this in a stackblitz maybe I could help to debug.

Comment: K. Pham if the answer above is a good solution for your question please consider accepting it as your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a time stamp on the end of the url with the current date/date, this should do the trick. For example, the below img source will generate a new random image for the catagory 'pilates' everytime it's loaded. If you want another catagory, just change the key word 'pilates' to something else:

```html
 <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?pilates#<%+new Date().getTime()%>" alt="" />
```